# probability question P(A/B)

Tags: probability

Let's suppose that we have  $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=0.4$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)=0.5$. I have to find $\mathbb{P}( A' \cap B)$ ..I know how to find $\mathbb{P}( A \cap B)$ which is related to $\mathbb{P}(A \setminus B)=\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \setminus \mathbb{P}(B) $..and here I find $\mathbb{P} (A \cap B)$ but how to find $\mathbb{P}(A' \cap B)$..?

Comment: What is $A^\prime$?

Comment: A ' means "not A"

Comment: @uer I notice that you have so far accepted only one answer to questions you have posed. To encourage users to engage with your questions, it is good practice to accept answers when you are satisfied you have understood them.

Answer (score 3):

$P(A^{c} \cap B)=P(A^{c} | B)P(B)=[1-P(A|B)]P(B)=[1-0.4](0.5)=0.3$

Comment: I have used the (I believe more standard) notation of $A^{c}$ to denote the complement.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\mathbb{P} \bar{A}\cap B = \mathbb{P} (B\setminus (A\cap B)) =  \mathbb{P} B - \mathbb{P}A\cap B $.

Comment: can I write it as P(B)/P(A ∩ B)?

Comment: Why? (also, no: it's a substraction, not a division)

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, we can find in a routine way $\Pr(A\cap B)$. It is $(0.4)(0.5)=0.2$.

To find $\Pr(A'\cap B)$, use the fact that
$$\Pr(A'\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B).$$
This equation holds because $B$ is union of the **disjoint** sets $A'\cap B$ and $A\cap B$. One can see that "algebraically." However, it is clearest to draw a Venn diagram.